# Race condition when getting the height and width of a matplotlib plot

Tags: matplotlib

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, or if this race condition is a bug in matplotlib. I am printing the height and width of an axes object several times, and there is a weird discrepancy between Test 3 and Test 4 below, which are both *after* the plt.show() call, but Test 3 is immediately after the plt.show(), and Test 4 is after a plt.pause(1). These (I assume?) should give the same result, but don't.

Windows 10 / Python 3.7.6 / Matplotlib 3.1.3

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f1,ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.set_xlim(-1,1)
ax1.set_ylim(-1,1)

ax1.set_aspect('equal',adjustable='box')

h = ax1.bbox.height
w = ax1.bbox.width

####Test 1
print('%i,%i' % (h,w))


ax1.scatter([0,0.5],[0,0],marker='s',edgecolor='k',alpha=0.5)

h = ax1.bbox.height
w = ax1.bbox.width

####Test 2
print('%i,%i' % (h,w))


f1.show()

h = ax1.bbox.height
w = ax1.bbox.width

####Test 3
print('%i,%i' % (h,w)) #=> 369, 496

plt.pause(1) #Highlighting race condition

h = ax1.bbox.height
w = ax1.bbox.width

####Test 4
print('%i,%i' % (h,w)) #=> 368, 368
```

Comment: Which backend are you using?  Did you consider upgrading matplotlib?

Comment: I think this is the correct and intended behaviour for all matplotlib versions. I think the confusion arises because you think that `f1.show` should not only show the figure but also force it to be drawn at that point in the execution (IMO completely understandable), and thus trigger the adjustment to the bbox. However, the figure is never actually drawn until the `plt.pause` command. You can test this by substituting your `f1.show()` command with `f1.canvas.draw()`. `figure.canvas.draw` does force the draw and then your last two print statements match.

Comment: IIRC, matplotlib only forces the draw when control is returned to the user (i.e. at the end of the script) or before `plt.pause()` commands.